# SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm getting this error. There is no my.cnf file in my etc/ directory. What do i have to do?

Comment: Are you on linux or windows?  On windows, you'll be looking for my.ini.  Increasing the connections should be handled with care to make sure that your server can cope.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MySql.

Comment: Douglas, where do i find this my.ini folder?

Comment: my /etc folder is empty

Comment: Assume you're on linux, so if you're running mysql you should have a /etc/my.cnf file.

Comment: There is nothing in my etc file.

Comment: and when i try to login MySQL i get this:
 Error while connecting to MySQL: Cpanel::DBI::Mysql connect('','root',...) failed: Too many connections at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/MysqlUtils/Connect.pm line 136 Error while connecting to MySQL: Cpanel::DBI::Mysql connect('','root',...) failed: Too many connections at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/MysqlUtils/Connect.pm line 136 ...caught